# Remove an array from an array inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have found advice on removing single elements from an array within foreach, but wasn't able to get it working when trying to remove an array from an array. Here's what I'm working with:

```
<?php
$all_posts = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'); // example array of WordPress post IDs from a get_posts function

foreach ($all_posts as $op_post) {

    $op_title = get_the_title($op_post);
    $same_title_posts = get_posts([ // get posts with same title
        'title' => $op_title,
        'post__not_in' => array($op_post),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids',
    ]);

    // example contents of $same_title_posts - array('1', '2')

    foreach($same_title_posts as $same_title_post) {
        // function
    }

     // before $all_posts loops again, need to remove contents of $same_title_posts array from $all_posts array

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest by using array_diff

```
<?php
$all_posts = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'); // example array of WordPress post IDs from a get_posts function
$same_title_posts = array('1', '2'); //
$arrays = array_diff($all_posts, $same_title_posts);

//then loop $arrays

foreach ($arrays as $op_post){
    $op_title = get_the_title($op_post);
    $same_title_posts = get_posts([ // get posts with same title
        'title' => $op_title,
        'post__not_in' => array($op_post),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids',
    ]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding - however I need to remove contents of $same_title_posts array from $all_posts array while within the second foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found - at the beginning of the function I added:

```
$skip_array = array(); // start with an empty array to avoid errors
```

Then at the beginning of the first foreach I added:

```
if(!in_array($id, $skip_array)) { // check if foreach ID has been added to skip_array
  // function
}
```

At the end of the second foreach I added:

```
$skip_array[] = $id; // add ID that has been processed to skip_array
```